# rails assign variable from controller to each function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I might be being stupid and I'm sure there is an answer to this somewhere I'm just not searching correctly,

I have this each loop method:

```
@events.each do |event|
  prices = []
  event.tickets.each do |price|
    prices.push(price.face_value)
  end
end
```

What I'm wanting to do is add the price to the event, so that I can use it in the view as `@event.first.price.first` for example?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you are creating `prices` array, you push values into it but it is not connected with the `event`.

Try this code:

```
@events.each do |event|
  event.prices = []
  event.tickets.each do |price|
    event.prices.push(price.face_value)
  end
end
```

### Edit:

If `prices` is not defined on the `event`, you can do something like this:

```
@events_prices = {}

@events.each do |event|
  @events_prices[event.id] = []
  event.tickets.each do |price|
    @events_prices[event.id] << price.face_value
  end
end
```

and then fetch the price like this:

```
@events_prices[@events.first.id].first
@events_prices[@events.first.id].second
```

Comment: theres what i initially thought the problem was but it returns prices method error

Comment: Prices isn't actually existing in the event which is probably the issue, I thought you could add to it?

Comment: what `@events` is? a list of hashes or custom class objects? If there's a class `Event` add a `@prices` instance variable and this code will work. If it's a hash, use `event[:prices]` instead.

Comment: @events is a searchkick response, I'm then filtering through them, I believe its a hash but i could be mistaken?